# Some Service interface are not supported in the MFGetService helper function

Tags: c++, video, ms-media-foundation, direct3d9

I'm trying to get a pointer to the `IDirect3DSurface9` and I use the the helper function `MFGetService` and I pass `MR_BUFFER_SERVICE` to the second parameter.While linking,I received a "unresolved external symbol `_MR_BUFFER_SERVICE`" error.

I looked up the definition of `MR_BUFFER_SERVICE` in evr.h and found a macro describing it:

```
DEFINE_GUID(MR_BUFFER_SERVICE, 
    0xa562248c, 
    0x9ac6, 
    0x4ffc, 
    0x9f, 0xba, 0x3a, 0xf8, 0xf8, 0xad, 0x1a, 0x4d 
);
```

And then I decided to make this GUID on my own and passed to the MFGetService, but then I get the error code `E_NOINTERFACE` while debugging.

```
//Here are the GUID struct I made:
const GUID FAR MR_BUFFER_SERVICE = { 0xa562248c,0x9ac6,0x4ffc, {0x9f, 0xba, 0x3a, 0xf8, 0xf8, 0xad, 0x1a, 0x4d} };

//The main code of getting a pointer to IDirect3DSurface9:
IDirect3DSurface9 *d3dsurface9;
IMFMediaBuffer* pBuffer = NULL;
hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(1024 * 10, &pBuffer);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"fail in creating Media Buffer", NULL, NULL);
}
    hr = MFGetService(pBuffer, MR_BUFFER_SERVICE, 
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&d3dsurface9));
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"failed in getting IDirect3DSurface9", NULL, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Linker error is to be resolved by additionally linking `strmiids.lib`

```
#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib")
```

2. `MR_BUFFER_SERVICE` is not available from generic system memory backed buffers you create by `MFCreateMemoryBuffer`. This service is only available from buffers which are wrapping respective D3D9 surface, esp. created with [`MFCreateDXSurfaceBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfapi/nf-mfapi-mfcreatedxsurfacebuffer) function.

The details are documented here: [DirectX Surface Buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/directx-surface-buffer).